# adjacent alignment of the div

Tags: html, css

How to move the div adjacent to the previous div...?
I gave the float property and reduced the width...
still not working....
providing my code below.....

http://jsfiddle.net/YQYBG/1/

```
 <div style="padding-left: 41px; padding-top: 10px;">
     <a class="" href="#">
        <img alt="change" class="defieLogo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/defie_logo_only.png">
     </a>
     <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px;">47657 Lakeview Blvd, Fremont CA 94538</p>
     <p>Tel: 510-657-8981 <span style="padding-left: 18px;">wwww.abcdfg.com</span></p>
 </div>

 <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 300px;">
     <p style="">Vendor No ABC01</p>
     <p style="">Purchase Order No 100001</p>
     <p style="">Est. Ship Date 2/24/2013</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me, removed everything but the two needed elements.

Applied

`float:left;`

to the first div.

http://jsfiddle.net/YQYBG/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` on the divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/YQYBG/2/